# Why SL is supporting BasicHttpBinding and not other bindings

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-5.0

I have one question towards the WCF Bindings with Silverlight (SL).

I have seen that, SL will only support the BasicHttp and netTCP alone and not any more bindings.

And also I have seen that, SL will have access only to the Core .Net Components and Cryptography components.

1. So, Can I assume like, "Since, all the advanced bindings in the WCF is supporting security,reliability,session etc, it is in need of the Cryptography things and that's why the SL is unable to support those kind of bindings."
2. Then if it is so, then my another question is, cryptography is dealing with only security.  So, SL can avoid supporting the security part alone for that Binding and it can support other features of that Binding right....

May I kindly know, is there any reason for this case, so I can understand bit more...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time the reason for Silverlight not supporting something is simply because Silverlight is a smaller *re-implementation* of the .NET framework.

So it's more accurate to say that Silverlight "has not implemented more bindings" rather than "doesn't have access to more bindings".

Some restrictions are also security related, but I think at least some of the remaining missing bindings don't fall under that category.

The reason for Silverlight being a smaller re-implementation is that the proper .NET framework is strongly wired to Windows and Silverlight also targets OS X - so Microsoft had to draw a line at where it's no longer economically feasible to aim for compatibility with the proper .NET framework.

The same applies to the new kid in the .NET family, .NET Core, which also targets OSes other than Windows.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the reply. So, Can I take it like,  
1. "The some/advance bindings in the WCF like WSHttp,Duplex binding etc. will have the default support if u r windows client and not for the non-windows or silverlight client [if they have not implemented to support those bindings].

Comment: @user3663241 Yes. Note that there are even some things that Silverlight supports that the proper .NET framework doesn't. They are simply different.